# difference in speed between Application.CalculateFull and AltGr+Shift+F9

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I'm currently trying to optimize my workbook (Excel 365) according to [the official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff700515(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and some other tips and tricks. Furthermore, I am not using any volatile functions, array formulas or conditional formats anymore. I've come quite far and the time needed to do a full re-calculation is approx. 0.2 seconds with a 'volatility ratio' of around 20% (though I did not use any volatile functions?). `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` takes 0.05 seconds longer, so in total around 0.25 seconds, barely a difference.

But If I do a full recalculation using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> it takes about 5 seconds. This is also the reason why I turned off automatic calculation and recalculate any changed data via the `Worksheet_change`-event, which is way faster though definitely not best practice. So, I'm wondering, what are the differences between both methods here? Why is the 'normal' way slower than calling `Application.Calculate` or `Application.CalculateFull`?

(to prevent too many nested functions I used two user-defined-functions, one interpolates some data, the second one just returns the (variant) input data if a condition is true and a string if not. To get an idea, when calling `Application.CalculateFull`, in total 1862 UDFs are evaluated. Maybe this has something to do with it?)

Thank you very much, cheers!

Comment: I think perhaps you're doing the equivalent of `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`  rather than `Application.Calculate` or `Application.CalculateFull` and that's why it takes longer

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Rory, unfortunately ```Application.CalculateFullRebuild``` only takes .05 of a second longer then ```Application.CalculateFull```, so in total 0.25 seconds. I'll edit my post